# Using Laravel Fluent how can I change this so it hits the database only once?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, fluent

In this line of code:

```
$ratio = $this->getColorRatioForDeck($communityDecks[0]->username, $communityDecks[0]->deck_uid);
```

You'll notice that I'm getting this ratio by index and I could get all of them by using a for loop like this:

```
$ratio = [];
foreach($communityDecks as $deck) {
    $ratio[] = $this->getColorRatioForDeck($deck->username, $deck->deck_uid);
}
```

However I would be hitting the database n number of times depending on how many $decks there are.

How can I combine the 2 queries in the code below so I can get the information in one go?

This is what I currently have:

```
private $take = 10;

public function decks() {
    // get decks created by the community
    $communityDecks = $this->getCommunityDecks();
    $skip = 0;

    return parent::ajaxView('mtg.decks', compact('communityDecks', 'skip'));
}

public function getCommunityDecks($skip = 0) {
    $communityDecks = DB::table('auth.users_deck_overview as deckOverviewDB')
        ->select('deckOverviewDB.username', 'deckOverviewDB.by', 'deckOverviewDB.deck_uid', 'deckOverviewDB.featured', 'deckOverviewDB.name', 'deckOverviewDB.description', 'deckOverviewDB.usage', 'deckOverviewDB.format', 'deckOverviewDB.private')
        ->skip($skip)
        ->take($this->take)
        ->get();

    // need to refactor this so it doesn't hit the database n times - ideally this for loop query should be combined with the above query
    foreach($communityDecks as $deck) {
        $deck->ratio = $this->getColorRatioForDeck($deck->username, $deck->deck_uid);
    }

    return $communityDecks;
}

public function getColorRatioForDeck($username, $deckUid) {
    // get the corresponding deck information to calculate color ratio
    $query = DB::table('auth.users_deck_overview as deckOverviewDB')
        ->leftJoin('auth.users_deck_cards as deckCardsDB', 'deckOverviewDB.deck_uid', '=', 'deckCardsDB.deck_uid')
        ->leftJoin('mtg_cards.cards as cardsDB', 'deckCardsDB.card_uid', '=', 'cardsDB.uid')
        ->select('cardsDB.name', 'deckCardsDB.card_quantity', 'cardsDB.manaCost', 'cardsDB.cmc')
        ->where('deckOverviewDB.username', '=', $username)
        ->where('deckOverviewDB.deck_uid', '=', $deckUid)
        ->where('deckCardsDB.board', '=', 0)
        ->where('cardsDB.cmc', '!=', '')
        ->get();

    $ratio = [];
    $ratio['cmc'] = 0;
    $ratio['{W}'] = 0;
    $ratio['{U}'] = 0;
    $ratio['{B}'] = 0;
    $ratio['{R}'] = 0;
    $ratio['{G}'] = 0;
    $ratio['{n}'] = 0; // colorless (does not count {X})
    foreach($query as $card) {
        $cmc = $card->cmc;
        $W = substr_count($card->manaCost, '{W}');
        $U = substr_count($card->manaCost, '{U}');
        $B = substr_count($card->manaCost, '{B}');
        $R = substr_count($card->manaCost, '{R}');
        $G = substr_count($card->manaCost, '{G}');
        $n = ($cmc - $W - $U - $B - $R - $G);

        $ratio['cmc'] += $cmc * $card->card_quantity;
        $ratio['{W}'] += $W * $card->card_quantity;
        $ratio['{U}'] += $U * $card->card_quantity;
        $ratio['{B}'] += $B * $card->card_quantity;
        $ratio['{R}'] += $R * $card->card_quantity;
        $ratio['{G}'] += $G * $card->card_quantity;
        $ratio['{n}'] += $n * $card->card_quantity;
    }

    return $ratio;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your function slightly to accept an array instead of an integer, consider:

```
$deckIds = [];
foreach($communityDecks as $deck) {
    $deckIds[] = $deck->deck_uid;
}
$ratios = $this->getColorRatioForDeck($deck->username, $deckIds);
```

Then your function:

```
public function getColorRatioForDeck($username, array $deckUids) {
    // get the corresponding deck information to calculate color ratio
    $query = DB::table('auth.users_deck_overview as deckOverviewDB')
        ->leftJoin('auth.users_deck_cards as deckCardsDB', 'deckOverviewDB.deck_uid', '=', 'deckCardsDB.deck_uid')
        ->leftJoin('mtg_cards.cards as cardsDB', 'deckCardsDB.card_uid', '=', 'cardsDB.uid')
        ->select('cardsDB.name', 'deckCardsDB.card_quantity', 'cardsDB.manaCost', 'cardsDB.cmc')
        ->where('deckOverviewDB.username', '=', $username)
        ->whereIn('deckOverviewDB.deck_uid', $deckUids) // <-- changed comparison
        ->where('deckCardsDB.board', '=', 0)
        ->where('cardsDB.cmc', '!=', '')
        ->get();
```

You may need to modify the rest of your `getColorRatioForDeck` function to accomodate the fact that you're now returning multiple records, I'm not sure - but there's an example.

Comment: That would still require 2 hits to the database since the query in getCommunityDecks() would happen first and then getColorRatioForDeck() query would happen. Is there a good way to get all the required information by modifying the query in getCommunityDecks()? I can deal with the aftermath and do the required changes that need to be made. I'm just not very good at writing queries.

Comment: They look like very similar queries yes? Can you just add the fields from community decks into the other query and return more data from the color ratio function that you currently do? As an aside, at least here you will only have two queries as a constant, where as before you would've had an unknown number of queries, growing with your database size

Comment: I was trying to combine them previously but was getting incorrect results so I was hoping to get some help on it. I'm using $query->take(); to get n at a time so it fine for query size.

Comment: Is there a way to run the getColorRatioForDeck() query as a sub query of getCommunityDecks() query?

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with Laravel, but what you could try is to have a function that will take an instance of `DB` as an argument, will assign all the joins and where conditions EXCEPT the `get()` function and return that object, so you could use one function, optionally add the extra conditions on with your function then call `get()` at the end of it all